# How can you flip a UILabel horizontally in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

How can you flip a UILabel horizontally in Swift?

I want `myLabel` to be "upside-down".

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Set an appropriate affine transformation, just as you would for any view. Take a look at the `transform` property of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

To flip the view upside down, you need to use the `transform` property of the view.

```
myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI));
/// flipped upside down. Can be applied to any UIView subclass.
```